# Ubercart refuses to believe it is updated

Tags: 7, ubercart, updating

I perpetualy get the "Security Update Needed" for Ubercart, even after updating.

The Update Modules page gives me: Ubercart (Security update)    Installed Version: 3.0  Recommended Version: 7.x-3.3 (Release notes)

But if I actually go to the modules pages, it shows that I have installed Ubercart 7.x-3.3

Is anything actually wrong? If not, is there any way to get rid of the constant update warning?

Thanks!

As requested by responses, here are the database system tables:

'uc_2checkout', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_2checkout/uc_2checkout.module'
'uc_affiliate2', 'sites/all/modules/uc_affiliate2/uc_affiliate2.module'
'uc_ajax_admin', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_ajax_admin/uc_ajax_admin.module'
'uc_attribute', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.module'
'uc_authorizenet', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_authorizenet/uc_authorizenet.module'
'uc_cart', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_cart/uc_cart.module'
'uc_cart_links', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_cart_links/uc_cart_links.module'
'uc_catalog', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_catalog/uc_catalog.module'
'uc_credit', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_credit/uc_credit.module'
'uc_cybersource', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_cybersource/uc_cybersource.module'
'uc_file', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_file/uc_file.module'
'uc_flatrate', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/shipping/uc_flatrate/uc_flatrate.module'
'uc_googleanalytics', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_googleanalytics/uc_googleanalytics.module'
'uc_google_checkout', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_google_checkout/uc_google_checkout.module'
'uc_order', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/uc_order.module'
'uc_payment', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_payment/uc_payment.module'
'uc_payment_pack', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_payment_pack/uc_payment_pack.module'
'uc_paypal', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/payment/uc_paypal/uc_paypal.module'
'uc_product', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_product/uc_product.module'
'uc_product_kit', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_product_kit/uc_product_kit.module'
'uc_quote', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/shipping/uc_quote/uc_quote.module'
'uc_reports', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_reports/uc_reports.module'
'uc_roles', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_roles/uc_roles.module'
'uc_shipping', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/shipping/uc_shipping/uc_shipping.module'
'uc_stock', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_stock/uc_stock.module'
'uc_store', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_store/uc_store.module'
'uc_taxes', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_taxes/uc_taxes.module'
'uc_tax_report', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_tax_report/uc_tax_report.module'
'uc_ups', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/shipping/uc_ups/uc_ups.module'
'uc_usps', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/shipping/uc_usps/uc_usps.module'
'uc_weightquote', 'sites/all/modules/ubercart/shipping/uc_weightquote/uc_weightquote.module'

Comment: Have you run update.php?

Comment: Dozens of times.  Occasionally it will act like it has upgraded and not give me the update warning for a page load or two, but then the next time I hit the admin menu it is back.  I've also updated from drush to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have two copies of ubercart in your drupal file system.

Check your database "system" table for the ubercart module path ( filename ).

e.g, raw SQL:

```
SELECT name, filename FROM system WHERE name LIKE 'uc_%';
```

Make sure the path matches what you expect.

If on linux, you could also run:

```
find /var/www/my-site -name 'uc_*' -type d
```

to list the uc_ folders ( type=directory )

Comment: Unless I'm not seeing it, I don't believe that's the case.  I've added the output of the query to the question.

Answer (score 0):

On the suggestion of someone in the official Drupal forums, I removed the whole ubercart module directory and re-downloaded the ubercart modules.  That fixed it!

Comment: Woops, nevermind, a day later and this no longer works.  Back to original bug.